# Change image source folder for mobile version with javascript

Tags: javascript

Sorry I'm a newbie with JS and I've been having trouble with some JS I found here on stackoverflow. My situation is that I have a div with two images inside, and I want to change the source path of those images when the window is less than 480px. My code is this:

```
<div id="bigFoto">
<img src="img/photo1.jpg" alt="text for alt" id="photo1">
<img src="img/photo2.jpg" alt="text for alt" id="photo2">
</div>
```

And The current script I'm running is:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    var width = $(window).width(); 

    if (width < 481) {
      $("#bigFoto img#photo1").attr("src","img/mobile/photo1.jpg");
      $("#bigFoto img#photo2").attr("src","img/mobile/photo2.jpg");
    }
    else{
      $("#bigFoto img#photo1").attr("src","img/photo1.jpg");
      $("#bigFoto img#photo2").attr("src","img/photo2.jpg");
    }
});
```

This script is working right, but now let's say I want that div to have 20 images, my guess is that I would have to add every one of them in this script right?

The real question: is there a way to target all images instead and just add the /mobile part on the source path? ,since the filename remains the same.

Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery's each function to loop through all the elements returned by a query

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    var width = $(window).width(); 

    if (width < 481) {
      $("#bigFoto img").each(function(index){
        var src = $(this).attr("src")
        var photoName = src.substr(src.lastIndexOf("/"));
        $(this).attr("src", "img/mobile/"+photoName)
      })
    }
    else{
      $("#bigFoto img").each(function(index){
        var src = $(this).attr("src")
        var photoName = src.substr(src.lastIndexOf("/"));
        $(this).attr("src", "img/"+photoName)
      })
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes! That worked like a charm!!! Thank you very much! So the function each goes trough all the images right?

Comment: The anonymous function that you pass to each gets called once for each element that matches the selector. $(this) gives you a reference to the element selected.